# How to build URL in Groovy

Tags: groovy, uribuilder

I think, I want to use [`URIBuilder`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/apidocs/groovyx/net/http/URIBuilder.html) here but not entirely sure...

I have the following code:

```
String serverURL = getServerURL(); // ex: "http://somesrv.example.com"
String appURL = getAppURL(); // ex: "http://myapp.example.com"
```

I now need to add the two together, so that it produces the following:

```
http://somesrv.example.com/fizz?widget=http://myapp.example.com
```

But I don't just want to use string bashing (`def url = serverURL + "/fizz?widget=" + appURL`). Plus I'd like URL encoding, etc. Again, I think `URLBuilder` is the way to go here, but not sure.

I've seen an example uses JAX-RS' `UriBuilder`:

```
String url = UriBuilder.fromUri(serverURL).path("fizz").queryParam("widget", appURL).build();
```

Now I just need to figure out how to do this in Groovy?

Comment: Why not just do it the same way as in Java then? Just remove semicolon at the end of the line ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`URIBuilder` is the way to go.

```
def serverURL = "http://somesrv.example.com"
def appURL = "http://myapp.example.com"

def concat = new URIBuilder(serverURL)
concat.setPath("/fizz")
concat.addQueryParam("widget", appURL)

println concat
```

Outputs:

```
http://somesrv.example.com/fizz?widget=http%3A%2F%2Fmyapp.example.com
```

Comment: It is important to import the lib groovyx.net.http.URIBuilder for it to work.

Comment: Which comes from external dependency `org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:<version>`